# Rails 6 and Vue component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, vue.js

I have an app in Vue, separately is working. But if I add it into Rails, I don't know how to create a component (I have many of them, using `v-for`). In my standalone code is

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import Bar from './components/Bar.vue';

const app = createApp(App);

app.component('light-bar', Bar);

app.mount("#light-bars");
```

But I am unable to create component like this in Rails `javascript/packs/light_bar.js`.

Please, how to create a component inside Rails javascripts? My `light_bar.js` looks like:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '../light-bars/app.vue'
import Bar from '../light-bars/components/Bar.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    components: {
      'light-bar': Bar
    }
  }).$mount('#light-bars');

  console.log(app);
});
```

I also tried to import and register the component in my app, like this

```
import Bar from './components/Bar.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      barsData: []
    };
  },
  components: {
    'light-bar': Bar
  }
...
```

and template looks like this

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Úrovně osvětlení pro různé situace</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <light-bar
        v-for="bar in barsData"
          :key="bar.id"
          :luxRange="bar.luxRange"
          :luxRangeName="bar.luxRangeName"
          :luxLevel="bar.luxLevel"
          :compensation="bar.compensation"
      ></light-bar>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

But no component appears. Any tips what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. But it is a little bit strange, I registered the component on both places, in `packs/light-bars.js` and also in my app.

```
import Bar from './components/Bar.vue';
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      barsData: []
    };
  },
  components: {
    'light-bar': Bar
  },
...
```

and

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from '../light-bars/app.vue'
import Bar from '../light-bars/components/Bar.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const app = new Vue({
    render: h => h(App),
    components: {
      'light-bar': Bar
    }
  }).$mount('#light-bars');

  console.log(app);
});
```